# Download a pdf file with Angular 6 and Swagger generated service

Tags: angular, pdf, asp.net-core, download, swagger

I have a controller (asp.net core) with an attribute:

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileContentResult), 200)]
```

and that returns a :

```
return File(myFileStream, "application/pdf", myFileName);
```

And swagger ***generated*** this:

model:

```
export interface FileContentResult {
  fileContents?: string;
  contentType?: string;
  fileDownloadName?: string;
  lastModified?: string;
  entityTag?: EntityTagHeaderValue;
}
```

service:

```
MyAPIPost(someData: string): Observable<HttpResponse<FileContentResult>> {
    let __params = this.newParams();
    let __headers = new HttpHeaders();
    let __body: any = null;
    __body = someData;
    let req = new HttpRequest<any>(
      'POST',
      this.rootUrl + `_api_url_`,
      __body,
      {
        headers: __headers,
        params: __params,
        responseType: 'json'
      });

    return this.http.request<any>(req).pipe(
      filter(_r => _r instanceof HttpResponse),
      map(_r => {
        let _resp = _r as HttpResponse<any>;
        let _body: FileContentResult = null;
        _body = _resp.body as FileContentResult;
        return _resp.clone({body: _body}) as HttpResponse<FileContentResult>;
      })
    );
  }
```

this gives errors since parsing to json can't be achieved. I could manually change the response type to Blob, and save the pdf file, but i wouldn't have access to the file name.
What am i doing wrong in this implementation?

is there any configuration for the code generation of swagger that i'm missing?
(the download works fine on the Swagger UI)